# I can't find my fingerprint-reader on my computer HP HP ProBook 450 G8 Notebook PC

Tags: scanner, fingerprint-reader

[image]

When i looking for my fingerprint device via lsusb, i find nothing.
My computer seems to don't have the required devices.
When i enter lusb fprintd-enroll i have this error message -> Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop
(Gnome version is 42.9)

Comment: Sorry for that
I'm using ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Gnome version is 42.9

Comment: have you checked this to see if it has Linux support: https://linux-hardware.org/